# C# WinForms access storage on Windows CE device

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a winforms app that runs on a desktop and talks to a local MySQL database.

All that is working fine. On the other side I have a scanner which runs Windows CE 6.0 that stores information about products, counts etc.

I am trying to get the winforms app to connect to the Windows CE scanner when it is connected through USB port but I don't seem to be having much luck. I have tried the obvious approach of

```
 private void txtSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string path = @"SkorpioX3\\\product\9441.txt";

            if (File.Exists(path))
            {

            }
        }
```

But the file can't be found even though it exists on the scanner

[Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPfdm.png)

What is the correct approach in getting access to the storage of Windows CE device?

Comment: Are you able to access `SkorpioX3\\\product\9441.txt` from Windows Explorer?

Comment: @mjwills yes, when I try this path in Windows Explorer it opens the file without any issues

Comment: It does as the drive name for the Windows CE device is "\". Please see the screenshot http://prntscr.com/hb7xng

Comment: @"SkorpioX3\\product\\9441.txt";

Comment: @K3rnel31 That's not a correct path, as stated in my previous comment with a screenshot, "\" is the drive letter for storage on Windows CE device. I tried escaping the backslashes as well but that didn't work.